# 1 of 3 font awesome icon not showing up on page

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm creating a page and I wanna use 3 font awesome icons,2 icons are working perfectly and are visible to the page but the third one isn't appearing I really don't know what the problem is,I tried to change the font awesome icon picking another one but still it doesn't work.
Here is the code of html
The third i class icon isn't showing up anywhere

```
 <div class="showcase2">
            <div class="container text-danger text-center">
                <h2 class="text-dark">WHAT WE DO?</h2>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-archway fa-3x m-5"></i>
                        <h3 class="text-dark">GROWTH MARKETING</h3>
                        <p class="text-dark">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, voluptatibus.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="fab fa-artstation fa-3x m-5"></i>
                        <h3 class="text-dark">ONLINE BRANDING</h3>
                        <p class="text-dark">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, voluptatibus.</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="fad fa-chart-pie-alt fa-3x m-5"></i>
                        <h3 class="text-dark">ANIMATED ADS</h3>
                        <p class="text-dark">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere, voluptatibus.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you share your css file?

Comment: you should accept @Ako's answer since your problem was resolved :)

Comment: you can do so by clicking the light gray check under the up vote and down vote buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the third one is that *fad* icons (look at fad class that you've added in the third one) is a pro icon that is a paid service. You have to own a Pro fontawesome account to be able to use it.by changing `<i class="fad fa-chart-pie-alt"></i>` to `<i class="fas fa-chart-pie"></i>` the third one will work but the icon is a little bit different.

Comment: Thank u very much man I wasn't aware of that,now it works I'm grateful